# nginx subdomain using domain config

Tags: nginx, proxy, web

When I browse to sub.example.com, it just goes to the index.html of example.com and doesn't use the subdomain config.

```
    # redirect all traffic to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server { 

    listen 443 ssl; 
    root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com; 
    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf; 
    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # With php7-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  sub.example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://#internalip#/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
}
```

IE: When I go to example.com it loads /var/www/html/example/index.html and when I go to sub.domain.com it still loads /var/www/html/example/index.html instead of redirecting to http://#internalip#/ like it should. any ideas? i must be doing something wrong with the config here.

Comment: The config seems fine, however if you go to `http://sub.example.com/` you will get a redirect to `https://example.com/`, whereas `https://sub.example.com/` should directly return the content of `http://<internalip>/`.

Comment: Sorry I thought I changed them all to example. Thanks, that was the issue. Any idea what variable the original request is stored in so that i can dynamically send to https? so i can do https://$url$request_uri  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hard coded a *permanent* (cached indefinitely by browsers) redirect for not only the example.com domain name but, since there are no other other servers defined for plain http on port 80, *every* (sub-) domain and *all* HTTP  requests gets redirected to `https://example.com`

you probably want something like

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

where you generate a redirect to the `$host` name used in the original request.

Please note that you will need to clear your web browser cache or use a new anonymous browser window to test and invalidate cached permanent redirects after you changed your config

Comment: Thanks this worked great!